# What "action" I do inadvertently can change a key binding?

Tags: bash, key-bindings, change-tracking

I have these two lines in my `.inputrc` file, in order to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle forward and backward through all possible completions on the command line,

```
"\t": menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

**Everytime I log in, these key bindings perfectly work**, but after some hour of work, always comes a moment when I realize that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> binding doesn't work anymore! (Whereas <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keeps working.) There must be some sequence of keys I hit (possibly inadvertently), something in the scripts I run, ..., that removes that binding.

One solution I think of, is to "track" a key binding and trigger some output to screen/file when that binding is changed. Maybe I could `echo` the last command executed before the change to a file, and check that file when I realize (with possibly a delay of several minutes) the change happened.

Other strategies would be appreciated as well.

Comment: could you run `bind -p` `bind -s` and `bind -v` before and after this happens to check binding is really removed

Comment: you may try to enable debug `set -x` and redirecting to file using BASH_XTRACEFD

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, by _script_ I mean not necessarily a bash script. For what concern your first suggestion, I've put the output of those three commands in a file. As soon as I'll experience the problem again, I'll run those commands again and compare the two outputs.

Comment: if it's not a bash script it could not change bash bindings as it would run in a child process

Comment: even a bash script if it's not sourced (run with `.` or `source`) it can't change current shell bindings, maybe it's another interactive shell (child of the first which didn't exit) in that case it's not the initial bash process

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, the output of those three commands before and after is exactly the same.

Comment: maybe "\t" should be changed to "\C-i", however i can't see why the binding doesn't work, maybe the function which does the completion has changed